# Chrome json path finder extensions

Tags: json, google-chrome

I have installed JsonPath Finder extension from Chrome webstore but when I tried to use it, the extension is grayout.I installed a different json path extenstion from web store and this extension behaved exactly the same as first one. I deleted those extensions and reinstalled but same result. I checked in the setting and all extensions are enabled. I have a win 10 pc with chrome ver 96.0.4664. Please let me know how to install jsonPath finder extensions from webstore and use it.All other extenisons I installed from Web store is working without any problem.